# C++ Polymorphism - Map of inherited classes

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have a `MovementSystem` class which inherits from a `System` class. Later I will have a number of `xxxSystem` classes so I will store the instances of `xxxSystem` (there is only one instance per system) in a map this way:

```
enum
{
    MOVEMENT_SYSTEM
};

std::map<int,std::unique_ptr<System>> systems;
systems[MOVEMENT_SYSTEM] = std::unique_ptr<System>(new MovementSystem());

m_entityManager.loadSystems(&systems);
```

The last line is there because I need my class `EntityManager` to have access to all the systems.

Therefore I have this method:

```
std::map<int,std::unique_ptr<System>> *m_systems; // this line is in the header

void EntityManager::loadSystems(std::map<int,std::unique_ptr<System>> *systems)
{
    m_systems = systems;
}
```

And finally in an other method of `EntityManager` I try to access the systems I have sent to the class this way:

```
std::unique_ptr<MovementSystem> mvt = (*m_systems)[MOVEMENT_SYSTEM];
mvt->update(dt);
```

But I get this error:

```
conversion from 'std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<System> >::mapped_type {aka std::unique_ptr<System>}' to non-scalar type 'std::unique_ptr<MovementSystem>' requested
```

How can I fix this and get the last line to call the update method from `MovementSystem`?

Comment: The expression `*m_systems[MOVEMENT_SYSTEM]` does not do what you think it does. Due to [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) it's translated as `*(m_systems[MOVEMENT_SYSTEM])` which won't work as `m_systems` is a pointer. You need to use `(*m_systems)[MOVEMENT_SYSTEM]`.

Comment: I have done it but the error is exactly the same.

Comment: Tangentially related: 1. It is probably a mistake to have a pointer to a map. 2. The whole design looks suspicious. Why do you need a map that essentially stores singletons?

Comment: I need a map to identify the different systems which I couldn't do with a vector (unless I know the order but that's not very clean), if you have a better idea please tell me!

Comment: Instead of having a map with N entries keyed by an enum, have a struct with N named fields. So your movement system is `m_systems.theMovementSystem`.

Comment: And then how do I have access to the struct from the other classes?

Answer (score 0):

```
std::unique_ptr<MovementSystem> mvt = *m_systems[MOVEMENT_SYSTEM];
```

There are two problems with this line. One, operator precedence is such that it will get interpreted as this:

```
*(m_systems[MOVEMENT_SYSTEM])
```

This means it will apply *pointer arithmetic* to the pointer `m_systems` (accessing the `MOVEMENT-SYSTEM`th element in an "array" pointed to by `m_systems`) and then apply `*` to that map, which is nonsense. What you wanted was this:

```
(*m_systems)[MOVEMENT_SYSTEM]
```

The second problem is that you're trying to copy a unique pointer. Which is precisely what unique pointers are designed to prevent.

What you probably want is simply get the pointer, and cast it accordingly:

```
MovementSystem *mvt = static_cast<MovementSystem*>((*m_systems)[MOVEMENT_SYSTEM].get());
```

Or, even better because it gets rid of unnecessary pointers:

```
auto &systems = *m_systems;
auto &mvt = static_cast<MovementSystem&>(*systems[MOVEMENT_SYSTEM]);
mvt.update(dt);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The first problem is fixed, and about the second one: it doesn't display an error anymore but the program crashes. The `cout` I put before the three lines is displayed but the one at the begin of MovementSystem::update() isn't. I did put one more `cout` and it turns out it crashes at the line of the `static_cast`.

Comment: @Urefeu That looks like a different problem, with a different approach needed (you'll need to do some debugging to verify all is as you assume), a potentially different [mcve] and so on. Try stepping through your program, perhaps use a checked `dynamic_cast` instead of my `static_cast`, etc. If you're still stuck, post your findings and an MCVE as a new question.